# A Christmas rebus

Tags: visual, rebus, language, seasonal

*-Overheard at a party last night-*

> "First, to my French friends: I wish you a "*Joyeux Noël*"!
>   - ...
>   - ...
>   - ...
>   - And finally, to my Spanish friends: "*Feliz Navidad*"!
>   - Oh, and to you, puzzlers..."

I couldn't hear the rest, but I manage to get what was destined for us, puzzlers. It was an image containing this rebus:

[image]

But what does it say?

Comment: Feliz Navidad :D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What about

> We wish you a merry Christmas

from

> "Oui Oui chew Americ Ritz mas"

because

> That's Noddy, and in French, as clued by the French text above, is Oui Oui; Gum is for chewing; Americ(as); Ritz crackers; plus in Spanish is mas, again, clued by the text above.
>  Thanks to @Sconibulus to getting most of it first.

Comment: So, it would be "and to you, puzzlers, and you, a merry Christmas"? No! And it is *not* an elf...

Comment: elf or not, it's still a hand, though :P

Comment: with the last edit about the *elf*  must be it :D

Comment: The boy is "Noddy" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noddy_%28character%29

Comment: @LeppyR64 so is said in the "because" part of his answer

Comment: @lois6b I hadn't seen the edit.

Comment: May as well have the link anyway. Thanks!

Comment: the only thing I dont get, @IAmInPLS is, if the person speaking says: "... to my French friends: I wish..." , why then to the puzzlers says: "we" ?

Comment: @lois6b It is a different phrase. Look at the one for Spanish friends

Comment: I can't believe that people didn't recognise Noddy !?!?!  I grew up reading about Noddy, and Big Ears, and Inspector Plodd (and I can't remember the rest of the characters :( )  We had about 40 of the books IIRC.

Answer (score 6):

I think it's

> Wish you a merry christmas

via

> Elf(? this one is least likely) Chew(gum) Americ(Americas-AS) Ritz plus(possible spanish mas, but if you say it fast enough it works either way)

for

> elfchewamericritzplus, which said fast enough sounds like "wish you a Merry Christmas"

Comment: Well, it's almost that, but your explanation is not convicing (an elf?).

Comment: I guess the "boy" is with the hand up meaning "I"